# How can i remove the dependencies of modules in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyinstaller, executable

Here i'm developing a standalone executable file, which is including pandas as a library. But the pandas have some dependencies("numpy") which is increasing my file size. Can anyone help me in this aspect.

Comment: From what I understand about Pandas, this is impossible as Pandas is built more or less "on top" of numpy and relies on it for most of its matrix functions. Take a look at this article. 
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/data-manipulation-visualisation-r-python/tutorial-data-manipulation-numpy-pandas-python/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But my standalone executable file is around 30mb still i want to reduce it.

Comment: only these 2 libraries(Pandas + Numpy) only consuming around 23mb